# Replace column values with mean y by factor in third column

Tags: r

I have a data frame with a response of y.  There is a column in the data frame that has 53 factor levels, X0.  There are 300 columns at two levels.

- 0 - means that column not to be included in results.
- 1 - means this row to be included.

data table is trainf and has 8000+ rows

```
y     X0    X10  X11  X12  X13  X14 ..... X300
55.2   a     0    1    0    0    1          0
45.2   a     0    0    1    1    0          0
95.0   b     1    0    0    0    0          1
105.0  c     1    0    0    0    0          0
```

Originally I wanted to only replace the 1 values in X10...X300 with the mean.

```
for (i in 3:298) {
a <- tapply(trainf$y, trainf[,i] , na.rm = TRUE, mean)
trainf[,i] <- trainf[,i]*a[(2)]
}
```

This worked fine - all the values of 1 in X10 were replaced by 53.0 which was the mean of y when X10==1, etc thru X300.  But the result did not generate the model desired.  An lm() of both the orginal values and the revised values gave same answer.

```
y     X0    X10  X11    X12   X13  X14 ..... X300
55.2   a     0   46.2    0    0    22.8       0
45.2   a     0    0     49.0  63.5 0          0
95.0   b    53.0  0      0    0    0          95.0
105.0  c    53.0  0      0    0    0          0
```

Now I realize I really want the mean at each level of X0.  That is, for all the values of X0 == a I want to get the mean when X10==1.  This generates the numbers I want.

```
a <- aggregate(trainf$y, by=list(trainf$X10, train_test$X0), na.rm = TRUE, 
     mean)
```

missing next line is where I need help

```
trainf?????? <- ????
```

This gets me a data frame with three columns

```
group 1   group 2   group 3
 0        1         114.44992
 0        2         152.17
 .....
```

group 1 is the levels seen in X10 - 0 and 1 are the only possible

group 2 is the X0 factor - factors were characters / factors but turned into numeric

group 3 is the mean desired

I tried lots of things (been about 16 hours on these couple of lines of code) but can't get the a data table back into trainf in place of the 1 values.  To complicate matters some of the X0 levels have only NA values right now so my "a" data table has some NaN in the group 3 which I need to handle.

Very new to R and to this site - so hopefully I gave you enough to help.  I think it should be a simple single line in a for loop similar to what I used in my first transformation of X10...   I see lots of questions about replacing values in columns but none that include replacing out of another data frame.  Don't know how to provide a small workable data set.

Better example of starting table

```
    y       X0  X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15 X16
    104.07  aj  0   0   0   0   1   0   0
    98.16   aj  1   0   0   0   1   0   0
    101.44  aj  1   0   0   0   1   0   0
    119.44  ap  0   0   0   0   0   1   0
    118.24  aj  0   0   0   0   1   0   0
    98.84   aj  0   1   0   1   1   0   0
    100.38  aj  0   1   0   0   1   0   0
    105.15  aj  0   0   0   0   1   0   0
    102.46  aj  0   0   0   1   1   0   0
    99.08   aj  0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    102.89  aj  0   0   0   0   1   0   0
    134.43  aa  0   0   1   0   0   0   0
    101.26  aj  0   0   1   0   0   1   0
    114.46  ap  0   0   0   0   0   1   0
    112.38  ap  0   0   0   0   0   1   0
    111.77  ap  0   0   0   0   0   1   0
    104.32  aj  0   0   0   0   1   0   0
    111.08  ap  0   0   0   0   0   1   0
    99.48   aj  0   0   0   0   1   0   0
    102.7   aj  0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    100.56  aj  0   0   0   0   1   0   0
    112.49  ap  0   0   0   0   0   1   0
```

In column X10 - X0 level aj has two use it values - rows two and three - average y for X10 would be (98.16+101.44) / 2 = 99.8

so after successful processing of X10 table would be

```
    y       X0  X10
    104.07  aj  0
    98.16   aj  99.8
    101.44  aj  99.8
    119.44  ap  0
    118.24  aj  0
    98.84   aj  0
    100.38  aj  0
    .....
```

X11 also has two aj - 98.84 & 100.38 = mean of 99.61

```
    y   X0      X10     X11
    104.07  aj  0       0
    98.16   aj  99.8    0
    101.44  aj  99.8    0
    119.44  ap  0       0
    118.24  aj  0       0
    98.84   aj  0       99.61
    100.38  aj  0       99.61
    105.15  aj  0       0
    102.46  aj  0       0
    99.08   aj  0       0
```

X12 has a single aa and a single aj - so mean would be the y value

```
    y     X0    X10     X11    X12
    104.07  aj  0       0       0
    98.16   aj  99.8    0       0
    101.44  aj  99.8    0       0
    119.44  ap  0       0       0
    118.24  aj  0       0       0
    98.84   aj  0       99.61   0
    100.38  aj  0       99.61   0
    105.15  aj  0       0       0
    102.46  aj  0       0       0
    99.08   aj  0       0       0
    102.89  aj  0       0       0
    134.43  aa  0       0       134.43
    101.26  aj  0       0       101.26
    114.46  ap  0       0       0
    112.38  ap  0       0       0
    111.77  ap  0       0       0
```

etc

Hopefully better definition of the file - not clear to me how I can get you a file.

After the change to how I read in the file the code provided runs.  But some answers wrong.  Looks like tempvalues not holding all the numbers they should - they appear to be holding only the last valid X0 and X?? match.

```
thevars <- names(trainf)
k <- length(thevars)
n <- length(trainf$y)
for (i in 1:n) {
  for (j in 3:k) {
    if (trainf[i, j] == 1) {
    tempvalues <- trainf[((trainf$X0 == trainf$X0[i]) & (trainf[, j] == 1)), "y"]
    trainf[i, j] <- mean(tempvalues)
    }
  }
}

    y       X0  X10     X11   X12       X13      X14           X15
    104.07  aj  0       0       0       0        102.9991667    0
    98.16   aj  99.8    0       0       0        102.9018182    0
    101.44  aj  101.44  0       0       0        103.376        0
    119.44  ap  0       0       0       0        0              113.6033333
    118.24  aj  0       0       0       0        103.5911111    0
    98.84   aj  0       99.61   0       100.65   101.76         0
    100.38  aj  0       100.38  0       0        102.1771429    0
    105.15  aj  0       0       0       0        102.4766667    0
    102.46  aj  0       0       0       102.46   101.942        0
    99.08   aj  0       0       0       0        0              0
    102.89  aj  0       0       0       0        101.8125       0
    134.43  aa  0       0       134.43  0        0              0
    101.26  aj  0       0       101.26  0        0              101.26
    114.46  ap  0       0       0       0        0              112.436
    112.38  ap  0       0       0       0        0              111.93
    111.77  ap  0       0       0       0        0              111.78
    104.32  aj  0       0       0       0        101.4533333    0
    111.08  ap  0       0       0       0        0              111.785
    99.48   aj  0       0       0       0        100.02         0
    102.7   aj  0       0       0       0        0              0
    100.56  aj  0       0       0       0        100.56         0
    112.49  ap  0       0       0       0        0              112.49
```

Comment: After nearly 30 hours of trying to get this little piece of code done I think its time to just do it the hard way in Excel and move on.  I could have done it a dozen times in Excel the slow and hard way by now.

Comment: OK - 30 minutes to write and run the Excel macro for the 8000x370 table.  It runs a little slow but sure beats the 30 hours spent with nothing to show for it in R - Jimmy got a lot to learn !!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I get what you're after, but it seems like you want the `group 3` column to be in your main data frame, as a separate column, is that right?

A few ways to do that, I personally like `data.table`. We'll call the output column `mean`:

```
library( data.table )
setDT( trainf )[ , mean := mean( y, na.rm = TRUE ), by = .( X10, X0 ) ]
```

So we're doing the calculation entirely within the one table, rather than extracting things first then trying to put them back again.

Comment: Will read more about this site so I can put in a example of the data table.  When I use code as you have written a new column added to the data table called mean.  Each row is the mean of y for all rows with a factor of X0.  It does nothing with regards to X10 values.  That is I get the same result for X13, X100, etc.  I also wanted the mean values to replace the 0 and 1 in X10, rather than be a new column in the table. - with the 0 values still 0 and the 1 values now the mean.  Hopefully I can get a mini table in here - thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

Your example isn't reproducible; i.e., when I try to write code for it I'm not entirely sure I'm giving the right answer, because your desired result assumes data I don't have access to.

Having said that, it sounds like you want this...

```
thetext <- "
y     X0    X10  X11  X12  X13  X14
55.2   a     0    1    0    0    1
45.2   a     0    0    1    1    0
95.0   b     1    0    0    0    0
105.0  c     1    0    0    0    0"
```

...changed into a table where a 1 at location `i,j` is replaced with the mean of y given {`X0 == X0[i]` and `column j == 1`}.

As rosscova says, it's easier to do this by just re-creating the table. My code has more lines than his, but I'm using base R only:

```
trainf <- read.table(text = thetext, header = TRUE)
thevars <- names(trainf)
k <- length(thevars)
n <- length(trainf$y)

for (i in 1:n) {
  for (j in 3:k) {
    if (trainf[i, j] == 1) {
      tempvalues <- trainf[((trainf$X0 == trainf$X0[i]) & (trainf[, j] == 1)), "y"]
      trainf[i, j] <- mean(tempvalues)
    }
  }
}

trainf
> trainf
      y X0 X10  X11  X12  X13  X14
1  55.2  a   0 55.2  0.0  0.0 55.2
2  45.2  a   0  0.0 45.2 45.2  0.0
3  95.0  b  95  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4 105.0  c 105  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

The problem is, the answers in each column are the same as if I had typed `{column}[({column}[i] == 1)] <- y[i]`. That's why a reproducible example is so important.

Comment: When I put this in my script I get a message I hate - seen it often in the last couple of days.  ..... Error in `[.data.table`(trainf, , j) : 
  j (the 2nd argument inside [...]) is a single symbol but column name 'j' is not found. Perhaps you intended DT[,..j] or DT[,j,with=FALSE]. This difference to data.frame is deliberate and explained in FAQ 1.1.    I can do [[i]] most of the time to fix this but too new at R to fix yours.   Will try to get an actual example in - thanks for the answer.

Comment: No, I'm using base R, precisely because the data.table package and DT commands give me errors that I cannot interpret.

Comment: Removed all libraries I had.  Put only library(base) - think that gets me to base R only - still getting an error message.  Error in `[.data.table`(trainf, i, j) : 
  j (the 2nd argument inside [...]) is a single symbol but column name 'j' is not found. Perhaps you intended DT[,..j] or DT[,j,with=FALSE]. This difference to data.frame is deliberate and explained in FAQ 1.1.
>

Comment: I'm not using a `data.table` command in my code, so I'm not sure what your issue is, but it's running successfully for me.

Comment: Was reading trainf in script with fread('../input/trainf.csv').   Changed it to read.table - trainf <- read.table('../input/trainf.csv') and the error changed.   Error in if (trainf[i, j] == 1) { : argument is of length zero.     Changed to trainf <- read.csv('../input/trainf.csv') and now it runs.  But wrong answers!  Will see if I can paste in your answers vs what I added a bit ago using Excel :)

Comment: Guess I goofed - I put the result as edit to your message - so requires peer review??

Comment: You've got a `data.table` object, even after you've removed the package itself. You'll need to convert it, and the easiest way to do that is with `data.table::setDF(trainf)`.